# How do I use a sysroot with autoconf?

Tags: c++, configuration, compilation, autoconf

I am trying to cross-compile fontconfig for a ARM device. I've got a sysroot with all the dependencies etc. Fontconfig uses autoconfig so I did this:

```
./autogen.sh --host="arm-arm1176jzs-linux-gnueabi"         \
              --sysconfdir="${SYSROOT}etc"    \
              --prefix="${PREFIX}"        \
              --localstatedir="${SYSROOT}var" \
              --disable-docs
```

However, there is no flag like `--sysroot` so how do I pass my sysroot to autoconfig ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you set `$CC` to your cross-compiler's path. You can easily add some flags:

```
export CC=gcc --sysroot=/path/to/sysroot
```

Note that this works with all tools so keep it in mind ;)

Comment: Bash is complainging about this.. "not a valid identifier" export CC=/home/user/repos/tools/linaro/gcc-linaro-4.9-2015.02-3-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/rauger/repos/tools/linaro/gcc-linaro-4.9-2015.02-3-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi/
-bash: export: `--sysroot=/home/user/repos/tools/linaro/gcc-linaro-4.9-2015.02-3-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi/': not a valid identifier

Comment: Seems more appropriate to do `CFLAGS=--sysroot=...`.  `CC` should be the compiler, and `CFLAGS` are flags passed to the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `./autogen.sh` calls ./configure, the `--host=` option makes sure the correct compilers are called, but does not make the created Makefiles aware of your sysroot.

In order to achieve that, you should add these environment variables before calling `./configure`, `./autogen.sh`:

```
export CFLAGS="--sysroot=${SYSROOT}"
export CXXFLAGS="--sysroot=${SYSROOT}"
export LDFLAGS="--sysroot=${SYSROOT} -L${SYSROOT}/usr/lib"
```

(My experiments needed the additional `-L` in some cases.)

Note: I define my path variables such as `$SYSROOT` without the trailing slash.

Furthermore, if your project uses pkg-config, you will need to teach it about your sysroot as well:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR="${SYSROOT}"
export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR="${SYSROOT}/usr/lib/pkgconfig:${SYSROOT}/usr/lib/${HOST}/pkgconfig:${SYSROOT}/usr/share/pkgconfig"
```

(There are so many additional paths, because on my Yocto and Debian platforms, the `.pc` files are spread around everywhere.)

After these measures, you omit the `${SYSROOT}` from your `--sysconfdir` and other `./autogen.sh` command line options - they are automatically assumed where required.